# HTML 5 Audio Detecting Play Delay

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm trying to measure the time between when the user clicks the play button, triggering audio.play(), and the time when the audio actually starts to play on the client. I'm just not sure which event to listen to, as per http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

It seems that 'play' and 'canplay' are giving me similar times, so I'm not sure of the correct one to listen to. It's rather hard for me to test since I have a fairly quick connection. I'm using the following code:

```
var time;
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
var uri = 'http://www.flashkit.com/imagesvr_ce/flashkit/soundfx/Creatures/Male_zombi_Zapsplat_8347/horror_monster_zombie_male_eating_body_001.mp3'
audio.setAttribute('preload', 'metadata');
audio.src = uri;

audio.addEventListener('canplay', (evt) => {
    time = Date.now() - time;
    alert(time);
});

audio.play();
time = Date.now()
setTimeout(function() { audio.pause(); }, 1000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/67vmr476/1/

Comment: In jsFiddle, it successfully shows timeout, what's the problem?

Comment: Not sure if this is the correct event to listen to, since 'play' gives me a similar time. Mainly since I have a fast connection its hard for me to tell which one is correct based solely on the number.